# When solving surface charge problems, why do we break the surface into symmetrical differential “stripes” that match the shape of the surface?

Tags: electrostatics

Say I'm trying to find the electric field intensity at a point $P$ on the vertical axis going through a center of a disk of charge of radius $R$ with a constant surface charge density $\sigma $, like this:

[image]

Why is it that I can't simply solve a surface integral? I suppose the answer is because, say I tried to solve the surface integral:

$$\vec{E}(P)=\frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon _0}\iint_{S'}^{}\frac{\sigma }{r^2}\hat{k}dS'$$

I would end up with something like
$$ \hat{k} \int_{0}^{2\pi }\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\sigma }{r^2}rdrd\theta $$

where the $1/r$ ends up diverging because of the bounds. Can someone clarify this for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance from the little patch on the surface to point $P$ isn't $r$, its $\sqrt{r^2+z^2}$.

Comment: I see. Thank you.